# How to turn a pandas series into a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I've got a dataset that looks like this:0                 DATE DECRIPTION DEBIT CREDIT BALANCE

```
1            28/04/2022 Rent Due 1,150.00 £ -£1,150.00
2    17/05/2022 Payment Received from Berns & Co 1,...
3              27/05/2022 Payment 1,150.00 £ £1,150.00
4                 28/05/2022 Rent Due 1,150.00 £ £0.00
```

Essentially a series.

```
def clean_data(s):
    if "Rent Due" in s:
        print("Rent Due")
        s = s.split("Rent Due")
    elif "Payment Received from Berns & Co" in s:
        print("Berns")
        s = s.split("Payment Received from Berns & Co", )
    elif "Payment" in s:
        s = s.split("Payment")
        print("Payment")
    elif "Electricity Charges" in s:
        s = s.split("Electricity Charges")
    print(s)
    return s
bv = data.apply(clean_data)
```

But I don't know how to use the split function in apply to transform the data to columns.

The first row is supposed to be the column names

But I could do that using:

```
bv.columns = ['DATE', 'DESCRIPTION', 'DEBIT', 'CREDIT']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n` parameters:

```
#create one column DataFrame and remove first row
df = data.to_frame('data').iloc[1:]

df[['DATE','new']] = df['data'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df[['DECRIPTION','CREDIT','col','BALANCE']] = df.pop('new').str.rsplit(n=3, expand=True)

print (df)
                                                data        DATE  \
1          28/04/2022 Rent Due 1,150.00 £ -£1,150.00  28/04/2022   
2  17/05/2022 Payment Received from Berns & Co 1,...  17/05/2022   
3            27/05/2022 Payment 1,150.00 £ £1,150.00  27/05/2022   
4               28/05/2022 Rent Due 1,150.00 £ £0.00  28/05/2022   

                         DECRIPTION    CREDIT col     BALANCE  
1                          Rent Due  1,150.00   £  -£1,150.00  
2  Payment Received from Berns & Co  1,150.00   £  -£1,150.00  
3                           Payment  1,150.00   £   £1,150.00  
4                          Rent Due  1,150.00   £       £0.00
```

Comment: Thank you Jazrael. Always swift and knowledgeable. Have to admit I've never quite got to pandas after Mr McKinney handed over the reins. I always liked .ix but that is back in the day.